# Draw direction arrow in polyline in MKMapView

Tags: mkmapview, mapkit, mkoverlay, mkoverlaypathrenderer

I want to draw a polyline with the arrow direction. I understand that is not already include in the Mapkit.

I tried to create a custom MKOverlayPathRenderer and override the drawMapRect but I'm a bit confused  on how to do this.

Is there any way to achieve my goal?

Here an example of what I'm trying to do

[image]

Comment: solved the issue?can u update

Comment: hi, Have You found a way to achieve it?

Comment: I didn't find any easy good solution. I tried to draw arrow depending of the direction of 2 coordinates. It  kinda worked but it was not so beautiful.